# JQuery: Get original input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Is it possible to get the initial value of a form input field?

**For example:**

```
<form action="" id="formId">
    <input type="text" name="one" value="one" id="one" />
</form>

$("#one").attr("value");   //would output "one"
$("#one").val();           //would output "one"
$("#one").get(0).value;    //would output "one"
```

However, if the user then changed the content of the `#one` input field to two, the html would still look the same (with one as the value) but the JQuery calls above would return two.

**JSFiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/WRKHk/**

I think that this must still be possible to get the orginal value, since we are able to call `document.forms["formId"].reset()` to reset the form to its original state.

Comment: `$(this).get(0)` is a ridiculous way of writing `this`... you *really* don't have to use jQuery here `:P`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The DOM element has the attribute "value" which you can access by:

```
element.getAttribute('value');
```

... which may be different from the element's *property* `value`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8xmqF/)

Note that you may call `.setAttribute('value', 'new value')` which will actually affect any `form.reset()` that is called after.

Comment: @David But why doesn't `$( this ).attr( 'value' )` return the same as `this.getAttribute( 'value' )`? I think it should...

Comment: @RightSaidFred You mean it's a bug? I find that hard to believe. The `attr()` method has been around for a long time. All bugs should have been removed by now. There must be a valid reason why `attr()` doesn't fully map to `getAttribute()`...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Define bug. If you expect `attr()` to give you the `attribute` value, then it was originally created with built in bugs. If you want `attr()` to be unclear as to whether you're dealing with the property or the attribute, then it works perfectly.

Comment: @DavidHedlund: The version was actually `1.6`, and they completely separated the attribute behavior from the property behavior. But there was so much broken code out there as a result, that they rolled back most of the functionality in `1.6.1`.

Comment: @DavidHedlund Backwards compatibility - that might be that valid reason I was referring to in my comment above. If that's the case, it's a shame.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: But what's the valid reason for the original, intentional behavior?

Comment: @RightSaidFred The original behavior? You mean why was `.attr()` originally designed to retrieve the DOM property value instead of the HTML attribute value?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Exactly. You originally stated *There must be a valid reason why `attr()` doesn't fully map to `getAttribute()`*. But in version `1.0` there are no backward compatibility issues. ;)

Comment: @RightSaidFred I meant why it doesn't fully map now (in 1.7). It didn't map in 1.0 because there was no `prop()`, so `attr()` was designed to retrieve either the DOM property or content attribute, and in cases where both would exist, the property had precedence (since it's more important). However, since we do have `prop()` now, I expected `attr()` to fully map (at last). `:/`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Oh, yeah that makes sense. It was a complete mess. I think they should have just stuck to it in spite of the code they broke, but instead they backed off quickly. I find it hard to believe that they didn't know there would be fallout. Very strange IMO.

Answer (score 35):

Try this:

```
$("#one")[0].defaultValue;
```

Comment: +1 for `defaultValue`, but you had forgotten to extract the DOM element.

Comment: Thanks, RightSaidFred.  Well spotted.

Comment: For checkboxes and radio buttons, you'll need to use defaultChecked instead.

Answer (score 9):

Input element got property called `defaultValue` that is storing the original value.

To reach it via jQuery, just use `.prop()`:

```
var value = $(this).prop("defaultValue");
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WRKHk/1/) - after changing to "two", the above will return "one".

Answer (score 2):

The HTML does change. Just that the browser's default view source tool always shows you the original source fetched from server. If you use something like Firebug, you'll be able to see the dynamic changes in HTML.

One way of getting the initial value is by storing it in an additional attribute in addition to 'value'. For example, if you serve out your HTML like:

```
<input type="text" name="one" value="one" origvalue="one" id="one" />
```

You can always get back the original value by calling:

```
$("#one").attr("origvalue");
```

Comment: +1 - a creative solution, but @David Hedlund's answer is the one I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
Save the original_values @ document.ready.

$(function(){
  var original_values = $.map($('form input'), function(input){ return $(input).val() });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try storing the value in data. For example:

```
$('#one').data('val',$('#one').val());
```

And then you could easily retrieve it later like this:

```
console.log($('#one').data('val'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var initialVal = $('#one').val();
alert(initialVal);
$('#one').live("focusout", function() {
    var attribute = $("#one").attr("value");
    var value = $(this).val();
    var get = $(this).get(0).value;
    alert( "Attribute: " + attribute + "\n\nValue: " + value + "\n\ninit val: " + initialVal +"\n\nGet: " + get );
});
```