# Resetting a single form field onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the code below for showing/hiding html sections on button click using javascript. In addition to hiding the section, when an alternative button is clicked, I also want to reset the specific fields to their default values but I'm struggling to do so.

```
function Prefs() {
    var x = document.getElementById('continents');
    var y = document.getElementById('countries');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
        y.style.display = 'none';
    }else if(x.style.display === 'block'){
        x.style.display = 'none';
        y.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the default value ? are they text boxes ? it would be nice if you post your entire code with the `HTML`.

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/8490541/2593099

Comment: @Sand. value=" "

Comment: #1 result for a google search for "mdn form element reset" yields https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset Particular Input Element in a HTML Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689658/reset-particular-input-element-in-a-html-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this,

```
function Prefs() {
var x = document.getElementById('continents');
var y = document.getElementById('countries');
 if (x.style.display === 'none') {
  x.style.display = 'block';
  y.style.display = 'none';
  x.value = "";
  y.value = "";
 }else if(x.style.display === 'block'){
  x.style.display = 'none';
  y.style.display = 'none';
  x.value = "";
  y.value = "";
 } else {
   x.style.display = 'none';
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want reset entire form use `reset()` method:

```
$('#yourFormId')[0].reset();
```

Or if you want reset specific input just use defaultValue propertie:

```
$("#yourInput").prop("defaultValue");
```